# How exactly works VmWare networking? Some doubts about my NAT configuration

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I am not so into networking and I have the following doubt.

I have a Windows system and on this system I have installed VMWare on which I have installed some VMs and the VM networking is set in NAT mode.

Running ipconfig on my host Windows system I obtain that the gateway is:

```
Scheda LAN wireless Wi-Fi:

   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:
   Indirizzo IPv6 locale rispetto al collegamento . : fe80::e5aa:8279:789e:dd3f%20
   Indirizzo IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Gateway predefinito . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

So the gateway have IP address: **192.168.1.1**.

Then I want retrieve the gateway from an Ubuntu VM so I perform:

```
root@kali:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.223.2   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.223.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

and the gateway is **192.168.223.2** that is different from the previous one.

My understanding is that it depends by the fact that VM are in NAT mode so they have their own gateway. Is this reasoning correct? Who is the gateway of my VMware VMs? Is it implemented by VmWare itself?

Another doubt is: on my Windows host machine my PC have the following IP address: **192.168.1.5** while on my Ubuntu VM **192.168.223.133**

My idea is that VmWare is creating a subnet in **192.168.223.XXX**. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that it depends by the fact that VM are in NAT mode so they have their own gateway. Is this reasoning correct? Who is the gateway of my VMware VMs? Is it implemented by VmWare itself?

Yes, VMware internally acts as a router for all VMs. It's implemented entirely by the VM software and the host system remains unaware of this. (VirtualBox does the same, whereas Libvirt-KVM uses the host OS routing functionality and the host OS sees a virtual interface for the guest subnet.)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to VMware Programs and run the VMware Network Editor and see what NAT IP addresses have been assigned and change them if you so desire. The addresses selected are above in your post. That will always be different from your host IP address and that is correct and normal.

Then any VM using NAT will use a "wired" network connection into VMware NAT and select a single address to use for the VM.

Using the Network Editor is helpful to see what is going on. I use VMware V15 (and all versions prior) and this setup is very standard.